# What color space is being used in Image Properties detection-Dominant Colors?

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I'm using Google Cloud Vision API to detect dominant colors in images for a personal project. As shown below, Vision API returned RGBA values, pixel fractions, and scores for each image I tested. I was wondering why Alpha values are always missing, and in what color space (sRGB, AdobeRGB, Apple RGB, etc.) should the RGBA values make most sense?

{"colors": [{"color": {"red": 196, "green": 193, "blue": 193}, "score": 0.37683305, "pixelFraction": 0.013152561}, {"color": {"red": 237, "green": 235, "blue": 234}, "score": 0.3126285, "pixelFraction": 0.97964054},

Answer (score 0):

According to the [API guide for image properties](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-properties), applications should assume sRGB space:

> The ColorInfo field does not carry information about the absolute color space that should be used to interpret the RGB value (e.g. sRGB, Adobe RGB, DCI-P3, BT.2020, etc.). By default, applications should assume the sRGB color space.